# Will changing the only the bundle name cause problems uploading app to iTunes?

Tags: ios

Xcode 6.4 and beta 7 will not permit me to change the name of my project and I've pretty much given up on the process (I've tried every conceivable fix: deleting derived data, clean build folder, reset simulator, run on beta 7, etc).

If I simply change the bundle name, on the info.plist file so that the display name is changed, and leave everything else alone, will that cause issues, either during submission or after?

Comment: If you want a different name under the icon, update the "Bundle display name", not the "Bundle name".

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you are after?

Comment: @Nicolas, ultimately, I was after changing the project name.  I've managed to do so, but it will not run any devices, only simulators.  If I try to build to the device, it throws a Mach-O linker error.  What I was considering is simply changing the display name on the info.plist file, but I'm unsure if that will cause any issues with submission of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping `Bundle ID` same you can change anything `bundle name`, `bundle display name` BUT you can not use a beta version of Xcode i.e. beta 7 to submit your app to the app store, you have to use Xcode 6.4